# Accessing an object property by key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking to make my code more efficient. I've written it like this because I can't find a way to access object properties by their respective keys. I'd ideally like to use a for loop to shorten this enormous chunk of code down. I'm open to restructuring my object, if that will help.

```
if (response.data[i].code == 'P01') {
  $scope.production['P01'] += response.data[i].hours;
} else if (response.data[i].code == 'P02') {
  $scope.production['P02'] += response.data[i].hours;
} else if (response.data[i].code == 'P03') {
  $scope.production['P03'] += response.data[i].hours;
} else if (response.data[i].code == 'P04') {
  $scope.production['P04'] += response.data[i].hours;
} else if (response.data[i].code == 'P05') {
  $scope.production['P05'] += response.data[i].hours;
} else if (response.data[i].code == 'P06') {
  $scope.production['P06'] += response.data[i].hours;
} else if (response.data[i].code == 'P07') {
  $scope.production['P07'] += response.data[i].hours;
} else if (response.data[i].code == 'P08') {
  $scope.production['P08'] += response.data[i].hours;
}
```

As you can imagine, $scope.production is an object like such:

```
$scope.production = {'P01' :0, 'P02' : 0, 'P03' :0};
```

Comment: This code *does* access object properties by their respective keys. Accessing a different object's properties is no different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var data = response.data[i];
$scope.production[data.code] += data.hours;
```